# Insert value into a ChartJS with different data label

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas, chart.js

On this ChartJS, I fetch data from txt file & I want to display them in a graph chart.
My problem is, on the console.log we can see 2 differents labels & 2 differents array of values. I want to display the 'Gabarit' on the same chart of the mesure value to see the default, but the problem is the difference of label length.

It's possible or i must creat medium value on the gabarit ?

[image: ChartJS, put a reference value and the mesure]

Answer (score 0):

You should omit `data.labels` and instead, provide the `data` for both `datasets` in point format. This is an [`array` of objects](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#object) having an `x` and `y` property each.

```
data: [
  { x: 10, y: 20 }, 
  { x: 15, y: 10 },
  ... 
]
```

Comment: Thx for your response but I tried this & I have problems with a length in the chartjs program. Impossible to display something in the canvas div